# Publishing extension to Marketplace

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, package, marketplace

I'm trying to publish extension to the magento marketplace. I receive an error when i press submit button on magento's web from:

> > Can't connect to package repository

[image]

i have added my `GitHub` repository to package's `composer.json`. But i still receive this message.

According to documentation, i can just publish my extension to `github` and reference it from composer (it think it is about 'require' composer section)
[magento doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html)

What i'm doing wrong? How to publish my package without this unclear error? Should i push my package to `packagist`?

composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "myvendorname/myextname",
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/myvendorname/repo"
    }
],
...
}
```

Comment: Are you still receiving this issue? BTW, you shouldn't push your extension on packagist.

Comment: i didn't tried since this post was created. Yesterday the extension was approved (without a package)